Go Workspace Looking Outside
I am fixing a broken module in a workspace in the directory layout at the bottom. Module 2 has a dependency on Module 1, but when I go build for Module 2 it'll reference the
Module 1, in the ~/go mod cache directory, Module 1 has a compilation error from upstream so I can't use that.
To no avail I've done:
go work init
go work sync
go work use

and checked go env GOWORK inside the directories and it works
Is there anything else I should be doing?
Directory layout:
    ├── go.work
    ├── module1
    │   ├── go.mod
    │   ├── go.sum
    │   └── main.go
    ├── module2
    │   ├── go.mod
    │   ├── go.sum
    │   └── main.go

Progress so far: So far I can get it to work if I use replace in the go.mod file

Why do you have a go.mod above module1 and module2?

@BurakSerdar thanks my bad. it should be go.work. I just corrected it

In that case, one possibility I can think of is a mismatch with module names. What are the module names for module1 and module2, and how are they imported?

Did you follow the "Add the module to the workspace" step in the tutorial? (i.e. run go use ./module1). Please show us the contents of go.work.
